# Reading in files from array of files

Tags: java, arrays, file, file-io, bufferedinputstream

I'm new to Java and am attempting to read in files from java, but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I'm getting IOExceptions and errors when I'm trying to read in the files. I just don't like how BufferedReader handles reading in files. I don't understand what it is attempting to do. I heard a friend mention BufferedInputStream to read in files and files from an array of files.

Question: How can I correctly, from the array of files, read in multiple files?

Comment: I realize there is no code which looks like no effort, but no matter how long I stare at java documentation, it just doesn't make sense to me. I was wondering if someone could make an example and I could study that code for BufferedStreams. From the little research I did do, I like the look of it better, and the description is better, but how do I actually do it?

Comment: [Lesson: Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use my Generic readFile class. I modified it to read an array of files. It used BufferedInputStream, which needs a FileInputStream. DataInputStream takes a BufferedInputStream as a parameter, so you also need a DataInputStream. I'm not sure how to directly answer your question...its rather general but I hope this helps you.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Foo 
{

    public void readFile(File[] myFile) 
    {

       FileInputStream fiStream = null;
       BufferedInputStream biStream = null;
       DataInputStream diStream = null;
       foreach(File file in myFile)
       {

           try 
           {
               fiStream = new FileInputStream(file);

               biStream = new BufferedInputStream(fiStream);
               diStream = new DataInputStream(biStream);

               while (dis.available() != 0) 
               {
                System.out.println(dis.readLine());
               }

           } catch (IOException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } finally 
           {
              try 
              {
                  fiStream.close();
                  biStream.close();
                  diStream.close();
              } catch (IOException ex)
              {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wants to tell you one more thing, if you are using java version upto 7.0, you must use try-with-resource instead. And to use PrintWriter in place of BufferedReader would be more easy here.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadListOfFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File[] listOfFiles = {
                new File("file1.txt"),
                new File("file2.dat")
            };

            int val;
            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                BufferedInputStream bis = null;

                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    // When end of file is found in file -1 will be returned and loop will terminate.
                    while ((val = bis.read()) != -1) {
                        System.out.println((char) val);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error in reading " + file + " file : " + ex);
                } finally {
                    if (fis != null) {
                        fis.close();
                    }
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error : " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```